# Relativity and differential equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, kinematics, coordinate-systems

I have a question regarding Misner, Charles W.; Thorne, Kip S.; Wheeler, John Archibald (1973), Gravitation ISBN 978-0-7167-0344-0. It is a book about Einstein's theory of gravitation.

In page 166 of chapter 6.2 about Hyperbolic Motion, the authors present a person feeling constant acceleration $g$ along the direction $x^1$. The authors get the following equations:

> $$a^0 = \frac{du^0}{d \tau} = gu^1$$
>   $$a^1 = \frac{du^1}{d \tau} = gu^0$$

And the system is solved by the authors to get:

> $$t=g^{-1} \sinh{g\tau}$$
>   $$x=g^{-1} \cosh{g\tau}$$

So obviously $u^0 = t$ and $u^1 = x$, but I am not sure about the change of variable between $t$ and $\tau$ to make the appearance of the Lorentz factor.

How do the authors solve the differential equation?

Comment: $u$ is the four velocity. $u^0 = dx^0/d\tau$, i.e. $dt/d\tau$, and $u^1 = dx^1/d\tau$

Comment: Take another derivative to get uncoupled second-order ODEs for $u^0$ and $u^1$. They look like harmonic oscillators but with opposite sign. Solve these, then integrate to get $x^0$ and $x^1$.

Comment: equation 1 ${\frac {d}{d\tau}}t \left( \tau \right) =gx \left( \tau \right) $

equation 2 ${\frac {d}{d\tau}}x \left( \tau \right) -gt \left( \tau \right)$

take $\frac{d}{dt}$ of equation (1) with equation (2) you get:

${\frac {d^{2}}{d{\tau}^{2}}}t \left( \tau \right) -{g}^{2}t \left( 
\tau \right)
$ The solution is $t(\tau)=\frac{1}{g}\,\sinh(g\,\tau)$

Comment: @Eli No, see John Rennie’s comment. Also, your solution doesn’t satisfy your equation.

Comment: @G. Smith
I see: equation (1) is correct but  equation (2) must be equal to zero.
The differential equation is :
${\frac {d^{2}}{d{\tau}^{2}}}t \left( \tau \right) -{g}^{2}t \left( 
\tau \right) =0$
and the solution is what i wrote bevor? check it please.

Comment: again: lets write it like this:
${\frac {d}{d\tau}}u_{{0}} \left( \tau \right) =gu_{{1}} \left( \tau
 \right)
(1)$

${\frac {d}{d\tau}}u_{{1}} \left( \tau \right) =gu_{{0}} \left( \tau
 \right)
(2)$

$\frac{d}{dt}$ eq (1) and with eq (2) you get:

${\frac {d^{2}}{d{\tau}^{2}}}u_{{0}} \left( \tau \right) ={g}^{2}u_{{0}
} \left( \tau \right) 
$

solution :
$u_0(\tau)={\frac {\sinh \left( g\tau \right) }{g}}$

Comment: @Eli You have the right equation for $u^0$. And you have *a* solution to it, but it isn’t the *right* solution; it shouldn’t have the $1/g$ factor. The general solution is $A\sinh{g\tau}+B\cosh{g\tau}$ and you have to figure out what $A$ and $B$ should be, based on initial conditions and $u\cdot u=1$.

Comment: @G.Smith What other conditions are needed to find A=0 and B= 1/g? The dot product of exp and inverse exp could also have worked, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution:

$${\frac {d}{d\tau}}u_{{0}} \left( \tau \right) -gu_{{1}} \left( \tau
 \right) =0\tag 1
$$

$${\frac {d}{d\tau}}u_{{1}} \left( \tau \right) -gu_{{0}} \left( \tau
 \right) =0\tag 2
$$

and the constraint condition that

$$dsq=\left( {\frac {d}{d\tau}}u_{{0}} \left( \tau \right)  \right) ^{2}-
 \left( {\frac {d}{d\tau}}u_{{1}} \left( \tau \right)  \right) ^{2}=
\epsilon\tag 3
$$

where $\epsilon=0$ or $1$

with $\frac{d}{d\tau}eq(1)$ and equation (2) we obtain:

$${\frac {d^{2}}{d{\tau}^{2}}}u_{{0}} \left( \tau \right) -{g}^{2}u_{{0}
} \left( \tau \right) =0
\tag 4$$
$\Rightarrow$
 $$u_0(\tau)=1/2\,{\frac { \left( gA+B \right) {{\rm e}^{g\tau}}}{g}}+1/2\,{\frac {
 \left( -B+gA \right) {{\rm e}^{-g\tau}}}{g}}\tag 5
$$
where $A=u_0(0)$ and $B=D(u_0)(0)$ are arbitrary initial conditions

with equation (3) and (2) we get for dsq

$$dsq(\tau)=\left( {\frac {d}{d\tau}}u_{{0}} \left( \tau \right)  \right) ^{2}-
 (g\,u_0(\tau))^2=
\epsilon
$$

thus:  for $dsq(0)=\epsilon$ we can obtain the initial condition
$B=B(A)$ and get:

$$B=\sqrt {{g}^{2}{A}^{2}+\epsilon}$$

with  $A=0$ and $\epsilon=1$ we get:

$$u_0(\tau)=1/2\,{\frac {{{\rm e}^{g\tau}}}{g}}-1/2\,{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-g\tau}}}{g
}}=\frac{1}{g}\sinh(g\tau)
$$

$$u_1(\tau)={\frac {1/2\,{{\rm e}^{g\tau}}+1/2\,{{\rm e}^{-g\tau}}}{g}}=\frac{1}{g}\cosh(g\tau)
$$
and for 
$A=1 \,,\epsilon=0$ we get

$$u_0(\tau)=e^{g\,\tau}$$
$$u_1(\tau)=e^{g\,\tau}$$

Comment: How did you get the constraint condition? And why should we pick A=0 and epsilon = 1?

Comment: @PackSciences This is because the 4 velocities  $u_\mu\,u^\mu=c^2=1=\epsilon$ , and for example with $A=0$ you can fulfil this requirement.

Comment: Why is epsilon = 0 possible? Why the condition A=0 imposed by the question? What in the question tells A=0 or epsilon=1?

Comment: @PackSciences for  particle with mass  $(\frac{ds}{d\tau})^2=c^2=\epsilon=1$ for a massless particle (light) 
$\epsilon=0$ so you get the light cone this mean that $u_0(\tau)=u_1(\tau)$ or if you want $t=x$.